# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\sqrt[n]{(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(b_1b_2\cdots b_n)}}{b_{n+1}b_n}$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Assume $a_n,b_n>0$, $b_{n+1}-b_n\ge \delta>0$ and
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<+\infty$. Prove
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\sqrt[n]{(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(b_1b_2\cdots
>  b_n)}}{b_{n+1}b_n}$$ is convergent.

First, we can obtain

$$\frac{n\sqrt[n]{(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)(b_1b_2\cdots b_n)}}{b_{n+1}b_n}\le \frac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\sqrt[n]{b_nb_n\cdots b_n}}{b_nb_n}\le\frac{M}{b_n}\le \frac{M}{a_1+(n-1)\delta},$$

but this seems to be helpless, since $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent.

Comment: You probably meant $\frac{M}{b_n}\le \frac{M}{\mathbf{b_1}+(n-1)\delta}$ at the end of the inequality chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $ \sqrt[n]{b_1 b_2 \cdots b_n} \le b_n$, and $n/b_{n+1}$ is bounded above, so that it suffices to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}
$$
is convergent, and that follows from [Carleman's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}
\le e \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \, .
$$